# Input abbreviation in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How do I input abbreviations in PyCharm like vim's `:abbreviate`?

I usually use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to debug my script. If I can define an abbreviation like `pdb<tab>` that will be much quicker to input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/live-templates.html).